# Building a map based iOS game

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center

I'm going to build a map-based game regarding a virtual subway system. However, I don't know what will best solution to get started on it.

Here is few details:

So the map contains different stations on different lines as any global subway network. How can I integrate this map within a database Or should I not work with a database? I need a structure that tells me like:

Line X has these stations on it - A, B, C in this order
Line Y has these stations on it - B, D, E in this order

Then it would be nice to have a feature that doesn't require building a graph as such manually that would permit discovering routes from one station to another directly. So one could query a route from A to E and be given A-B, B-E.

Can anyone give me any hint on how to get started on this? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your map the same as the real world one? Or is it a really virtual cartography?

Comment: this isn't a question for SO I think... SO is about specific programming issues not about general advice. This will only result in different opinions about what's best (if at all) :/

Comment: Do you only want to know what data structure to use for the map? In this case it isn't iOS related, please edit the tags.

Comment: It is a question of how to implement a map system which I think has been answered with the graph answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Structure: you want a "graph" (or "directed graph" if you want some routes that are 1-way).

Algorithms: there are *lots* of famous algorithms for auto-detecting routes and "shortest routes" given a "graph". If you google for "graph shortest route algorithms" or "DAG algorithms" you should find many examples.

Simplest implementation:

```
@interface GraphNode : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *adjacentNodes; // array of the links to adjacent nodes

@end

@interface GraphLink : NSObject

@property GraphNode *start, *end; // joins a pair of nodes

@end

@interface GraphRoute : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *links; // array of GraphLink instances, connecting a string of nodes

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a map based game, you should try Zwoptex and it's sprite sheet system.

It stores map tiles in a plist and then you can import the sprite sheet and have your objects interact with the tiles!

Check it out here: zwoptexapp.com/